# What does a coinbase output script look like?

Tags: transactions, script

What does a coinbase output script look like and how would it be used to fund a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Coinbase transactions are almost identical to normal transactions.

The only difference is that they have exactly 1 input, which must have a special form (which would be invalid for non-coinbase transactions).

There is no difference between the outputs of coinbase transactions and others*. So just like any other transaction, they can have 1 or more outputs, and all those outputs have an amount and a script (address). Each of those outputs result in a new UTXO that is spendable by anyone who can sign for that script/address.

(*) Coinbase outputs have a special rule that they can only be spent after 100 blocks, instead of immediately. This is to prevent reorganizations from wiping out whole sequences of dependent transactions.